# Add a word to URL and redirect to the new url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

my pdf files have adresses like any string...-file.pdf. They will change to any string ... -new-file.pdf
i tried to redirect with

```
 RewriteRule ^-file\.pdf$ ^-new-file.pdf$ [R=301,L,NC]
```

but it doesn't work.
What can be done to proper redirect them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it's for files like xxxx-file.pdf...

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-file\.pdf$ $1-new-file.pdf [R=301,L,NC]
```